# Oven power usage estimation

Tags: power, appliances

Does an oven draw less power when used at a lower setting?

I'm trying to calculate the cost of running my oven on the lowest setting as a dehydrator. Wattage is 4800 kWh/cycle is .92 and my cost for electricity is 10c/kWh

Comment: *I'm trying to calculate the cost of running my oven* You can only do that if you know precisely how much time the oven will be on and off over a long time. Since the oven will change the on/off time depending on external conditions and how much stuff you put in and what temperature that stuff has. So as dim suggests, **measure it** using a wattmeter, calculating it isn't really an option.

Comment: Please edit your question to have a title that actually describes the content of the question.

Answer (score 6):

Summary

An oven costs less to run when used at a lower temperature setting.

Detail

'An oven', a domestic oven (though 4.8kW sounds bigger than your average domestic oven), controls its temperature by cycling a fixed power heater on and off. While the heater is on, it uses the same power, regardless of the temperature setting. However, at a lower temperature setting, it spends more time off than on, so the average power is lower.

Once an oven has come up to the set temperature, the average heat input only has to match the heat losses. As the heat losses will be lower when the oven set temperature is lower, the average heat input, and therefore the cost of running, will also be lower.

It's not the sort of thing you can calculate, without knowing the construction of the oven, the insulation in the sides, the amount of hot air that leaks from inside to out, and then you'll only end up with a rough estimate. It's the sort of thing that you measure. There are two ways to do this.

a) Let it come up to temperature. Sit in front of it with a timepiece and a pad of paper. Record the times of switch-on and switch-off of the heating element, there is an indicator light on most ovens to show when it's heating, over several cycles. Calculate the fractional on time. Multiply the rated heater power by that fraction.

b) If you have access to its power supply, put a wattmeter in series with it. Let the oven come up to temperature, zero the wattmeter and let it run for several on/off cycles, ideally an integer number of complete cycles for best accuracy.

Comment: Thank you so much. Do you reckon there is any way to estimate the consumption of the oven on its lowest setting? Or how can I even calculate the "standard" power consumption?

Comment: @C.P.H. its complicated to calculate. You need to know the time that the element is ON for compared to OFF. This will depend on what is in the oven, temperature outside the over and how well thermally insulated the oven is.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will consume less. Just like a heater, a refrigerator, or almost any device, setting it at a lower setting will need less power, and will have less impact on your bill.

However, you will have hard time guessing what will be the actual power consumption solely based on the device specs and the position of the setting buttons. The only reliable way to get this information is to actually try and put a wattmeter (even a cheap one) to measure the consumption, because it depends on too many factors.

Answer (score 0):

You can wait until it stabilizes and sit there with a stopwatch and measure the duty cycle D = ton/(toff+ton), then multiply that by the full-power wattage in kW, run time (in hours) and your cost per kWh.

That will get you close enough for government work.

There are cheap and reasonably accurate devices that will work on a plug-in product such as the [Kill-A-Watt](http://www.p3international.com/products/p4400.html), but it's much harder if you have wired-in oven. If you are talking about a countertop toaster oven, it might be a good solution.